# Keycloak pre-redirect logic

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I'm looking into using Keycloak with my Spring Boot server and it seems like whenever you navigate to an endpoint protected by Keycloak, it will automatically redirect to a login screen.

My question is, is it possible to get a control on the request before deciding to redirect to the Keycloak login page?

I could first hit an unprotected endpoint first, do some logic then redirect manually to the protected one but perhaps there is a better built in way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you need to achieve exactly so I can only answer vaguely.

- You could add the "action" you need to the [authentication flow](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_authentication-flows), if the "action" Keycloak provides match your need.
- You can define [new required actions](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#required-action-walkthrough) if needed.
- You can modify the login page template and execute some javascript to extract the information you want to grab.
- You can go all the way and implement your own [authentication SPI](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_auth_spi) and do whatever you wish to do.

Comment: I'm looking to essentially check the contents of the request, query my DB and do some checks before deciding whether or not I even want to display the Keycloak login page to the user. Would that be something doable via the authentication SPI?

Comment: Yes. If I were to do it I'd rather put some javascript in the login page template and hide the login form until you want to display it.
I'd be more comfortable to answer if you told me what was the alternative - what happens when you *don't* want to display the Keycloak login page.